# When exactly would you use ".[^.]*" or ".??*" glob patterns?

Tags: shell, command-line, wildcards

I'm trying to understand Linux, its command-line and this quote:

> You can run into problems with globs
> because `.*` matches `.` and `..` (the current and parent directories). 
> You may wish to use a pattern such as `.[^.]*` or `.??*` to get all dot files
> *except* the current and parent directories.
>
>       <sup>Source: [*How Linux Works: What Every Superuser Should Know*
>       by Brian Ward, 2nd Edition](https://www.academia.edu/32343435/How_Linux_Works_2nd_Edition), 
>
>             Section 2.7 “Dot Files”, page 23
>       <sup>(Requires registration/login)</sup>
>
>       or   [*How Linux Works: What Every Superuser Should Know*
>       by Brian Ward, 3rd Edition](https://dokumen.pub/how-linux-works-what-every-superuser-should-know-3nbsped-9781718500402-9781718500419-1593270356-2004002692.html), 
>
>             Section 2.7 “Dot Files”, page 22</sup>

When exactly (in what command) would you use `.[^.]*` or `.??*`?

Comment: `.??*` would not match the file `.X` -- `.??*` matches a dot, then any character *then another character* then zero or more characters

Comment: One recommendation if you want to match all dot files without duplicates, use both of these together: .[^.] and .??*  The first matches all two-letter files starting with dot, but not dot-dot. The second matches all dot files of three characters or more. That combined with a * which matches all non-dot files will match all files inside the current folder.

Comment: The recommended solution by others of .[^.]* will fail to match files of 3 or more characters that start with dot-dot. Not that that's a common occurrence...

Answer (score 12):

That's to work around a bug/misfeature in shells other than `zsh`, `fish` and the descendants of the Forsyth shell (including `pdksh` and derivatives)¹, whereby the expansion of the `.*` glob includes `.` and `..` (on systems (most, unfortunately) where `readdir()` returns them)

With those shells,

```
chmod -R og-rwx .*
```

for instance would recursively remove rwx permissions to the current (`.`) and parent (`..`) directories instead of just the hidden files and directories in the current directory.

It's particularly bad for commands that do things recursively or act on directories like `ls .*`, `chown -R .*`, `find .*`, `grep -r blah .*` but it's still annoying for most other commands and I can't think of any commands for which you'd want to have those `.` and `..` included in the list of files passed to them.

[A safeguard had to be added to the `rm` utility](/a/90075) to work around that misfeature as too many people were tripping on `rm -rf .*`.

With `*` added, it's also used to pass all files (hidden or not) as arguments to a command (`cmd -- .[!.]* ..?* *`), for which [you'll find other workarounds depending on the shell](/a/264571).

The `.[^.]*` glob (`.[!.]*` in Bourne/POSIX shells) excludes `.` (as it matches on filenames with at least two characters) and `..` (as the second character is `.` which doesn't match `[^.]`), but also excludes files like `..foo`, for which you need the second glob `..?*`.

Those `.` and `..` are tools for directory traversal, it's a mistake that they should be listed like ordinary files. POSIX requires them to be understood in path components (like in `open(".")`, `stat("foo/../bar")`) but not necessarily be implemented as directory entries nor included in `readdir()`.

Still, most systems still do implement those like in the early Unices as hard links, and most of those that don't will still fake entries for them in the output of `getdents()`/`readdir()`.

With `bash`, an alternative is to turn the `dotglob` option on and use:

```
chmod -R og-rwx [.]*
```

(though beware that if there's no non-hidden file, it could  change  the permissions of the `[.]*` file unless you had the `failglob` option on to mimic the behaviour of `zsh`/`fish`).

As a history note, filenames starting with `.` being hidden files were [born from a coding mistake from someone trying to skip `.` and `..` in the first place](/a/568524). It's ironical that when trying to do things with hidden files we would run into the same problem.

---

<sup>¹ see also the `globskipdots` option in bash 5.2+</sup>

Answer (score 7):

When you'd like to move all files and directories with hidden names (starting with a dot) to another location:

```
mv .[^.]* old-dot-files/
```

Or, whenever you'd like to do anything on all dot-files or dot-directories in a directory:

```
for name in .[^.]*; do
   # process "$name"
done
```

Note that the pattern `.??*` requires the matched names to have at least three characters, so names like `.a` will not be picked up.  `.[^.]*` on the other hand will skip anything with a double dot at the start of the name.

It may be better to explicitly test the matched names:

```
for name in .*; do
    # expecting a regular file
    if [ -f "$name" ]; then
        # process "$name"
    fi
done

for name in .*; do
    # expecting a directory other than . and ..
    if [ -d "$name" ] && [ "$name" != '.' ] && [ "$name != '..' ]; then
        # process "$name"
    fi
done
```

---

In my experience, wanting to do something an all dot-file or dot-directories in a directory happens extremely seldom.

Comment: But `.[^.]*` would miss files named `..foo`.  It's odd that negative patterns like this are still a pain to this day.

Comment: @SatōKatsura That's very true.

Comment: Interestingly, zsh `.*` ignores `.` and `..`. Yet another reason to use it :-)

Comment: @Kevin This is also true for `pdksh`, but not in `ksh93` by default.