# Copying [use of cp] issue

Tags: bash, cp, gnome-shell

I have a couple of sub-folders mounted on */mnt*. One is */mnt/data*, and the other is */mnt/1804iso*. The */data* includes data folders and files mounted from another disk, and */1804iso* includes a mounted ISO file whose contents I wanted to copy to folder */media/benny/0EB4-95E2/* which is a mounted flash-drive.

So I opened **bash** and typed **`sudo cp -Rn /mnt/1804iso/.* /media/benny/0EB4-95E2/`**. I would normally have omitted the period before wildcard asterisk **/*/**, but if I do that then a hidden file within the ISO does not copy over. So with this command one strange thing occurred. After copying over the ISO files correctly, then it started to copy over the */mnt/data* folders and files as well. I cannot see why that can happen as there is no reference to that folder, unless my understanding of the command part `/mnt/1804iso/.*` is totally flawed.

Could someone kindly explain why my `/mnt/data` folder was included for copying?

Comment: Possibly related: [`command .*` acts on the parent directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192656/command-acts-on-the-parent-directory/192782#192782)

Comment: Yes there is a reference: every directory contains `..` a reference to its parent directory.

Comment: See also the nice discussion at [Linux command line: glob confusion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/392479/65304)

Comment: `shopt -s dotglob`, will make `*` also match most files starting with a `.`, but not `.` and `..`.

Answer (score 9):

`.*` will expand to your hidden file, `.`, and `..`. This is an unfortunate part of how Bash [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion) works: there is a directory entry called `..`, which consists of an initial `.` and then any number of characters after it, so it's matched by `.*` and included.

You can see this happen by running e.g.:

```
echo /mnt/1804iso/.*
```

which will list out `/mnt/1804iso/.` and `/mnt/1804iso/..` along with the rest.

`../data` is your `data` directory. You will end up with a directory structure in the destination like this:

```
.hidden
xyz
data/
data/...
1804iso/.hidden
1804iso/xyz
...
```

That is, you'll actually end up with *two* copies of everything you wanted to copy, plus all that stuff you didn't. If you use `cp -Rnv` you'll see what it's copying and where to as it goes.

Some other shells will be nicer about this. In zsh, it would have done closer to what you want: *only* the hidden file would have been copied. In Bash, you could use `cp src/.[^.]* dest` to *almost* match the zsh behaviour, and list two source locations. Alternatively, you can [run `shopt -s dotglob` beforehand](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Shopt-Builtin), and then `src/*` will expand to *include* the dotfiles, but *exclude* the `.` and `..` entries (but this may lead to doing things you didn't mean to later on, so be careful).

---

For what you actually wanted to do, I suggest using [rsync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) instead:

```
rsync -avx /mnt/1804iso/ /media/benny/0EB4-95E2/
```

This will copy the *contents* of the `1804iso` directory to the destination (note final slash!), including any hidden files.

Comment: I think I follow you. Because of my use of .*, I end up with an option of /mnt/1804iso/.. which is the equivalent of my parent folder `/mnt` in this case. So, not only does /mnt/1804iso/ get copied but everything else within `/mnt` Is that right? I think `rsync` is safer, but I tend to use that for back-ups ratrher than simple file/folder copying.

Comment: Probably. It may depend a little on exactly how your `cp` implementation works (some will fail early and stop trying), but you've definitely asked it to copy `1804iso`'s parent directory recursively.

Comment: Your bash example is not quite equivalent, since it would miss a file named `..foo`

Comment: @NateEldredge Good point! I... don't think that's worth fixing, but I'll note that it's not fully equivalent.

Comment: I think `.[^.]* ..?*` would work.

Answer (score 3):

The pattern `/mnt/1804iso/.*` expands to, amongst possibly other things, the directory entry `/mnt/1804iso/..`, which is the same as `/mnt`.  I'm geussing that's why it started copying `/mnt/data`.

In this case, I would just use `rsync`:

```
rsync -ai /mnt/1804iso/ /media/benny/0EB4-95E2
```

This would copy all of `/mnt/1804iso`, including hidden files, into `/media/benny/0EB4-95E2`.  Leaving off the `/` at the end of the source directory would create a `1804iso` directory below the target directory.

Alternatively, enable the `dotglob` shell option in `bash` with `shopt -s dotglob` to make `*` match hidden names as well as non-hidden names (but not `.` or `..`). Then use

```
cp -Rn /mnt/1804iso/* /media/benny/0EB4-95E2/
```